# Using array with manual size management, vs. other data structure which self-manages its size

Tags: vba

VBA allows defining dynamically resizable arrays:

```
Dim s() As String
For i = 0 To ... 'some end condition
    Redim Preserve s(i)
    s(i) = 'fill with some value
Next
```

This is rather error prone. There are other collections that are self-resizing, such as a VBA `Collection`:

```
Dim col As New Collection
For i = 0 To ... 'some end condition
    s.Add 'fill with some value
Next
```

or `Scripting.Dictionary` (with a reference to **Microsoft Scripting Runtime**):

```
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
For i = 0 To ... 'some end condition
    s.Add i, 'fill with some value
Next
```

or `ArrayList` (with a reference to **mscorlib**):

```
Dim al As New ArrayList
For i = 0 To ... 'some end condition
    al.Add 'fill with some value
Next
```

What practical<sup>1</sup> benefits are there to manually managing the size of the array?

<sup>1. Presumably it would make a difference in embedded programming, or some gaming engine that needs close-to-the metal performance; but if you are using VBA for this purpose, then you deserve what you get.</sup>